# Can we improve tags filter cards

Tags: feature-request, design, tags-page

[Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) page shows a tag with the card with x questions and y asked today, z this duration, all good. *Can we show z this duration in a new line (option 1) or in one line (option 2)?*

[image]

*Option 1*

[image]

*Option 2*

[image]

Comment: Your option one has a floating comma just kinda hanging out. Is that intentional?

Comment: Thanks, @Catija. I just forgot to remove "," or we can place it at end of *y asked today*

Comment: This problem is more pronounced on international sites(in [SO.ja](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3241)). https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQKTw.png -